# How to extract integer part and fractional part of a decimal number?

Tags: fp

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fp}
\def\x{59.3612}
\begin{document}
\noindent
x = \x\\
%what to write here?
int(x) = 59\\
frac(x) = 3612
\end{document}
```

What functions should I call to get 59 and 3612 out of \x?

Comment: The easiest would be to split the string at the dot. Is there a reason why you want to calculate the values?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "Is there a reason why you want to calculate the values?" - no. Can you suggest an answer with split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note from `xint` package developer:
>
> The documentation is not clear enough that `\xintDecSplitR` is an *integer* only macro (in fact it is mainly used internally, but some forgotten reason I gave it a public interface). Thus the spurious dot is an after-effect from using the macro on unexpected input. It could have been spurious `!` or spurious `;` if I had coded it otherwise internally. By luck the dot indeed can be removed by `\xintNum`.
>
> **I thus recommend rather egreg's approach**, because this one works for accidental reasons. `xint` implemented decimal numbers at the same time as fractions and is lacking utilities which makes perfect sense for fixed point numbers only. Thus there is no high level one-shot interface to what is asked here.

---

Here's a way to do it with `xint`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\def\x{59.3612}

\newcommand{\getint}[1]{\xintNum{#1}\relax}
\newcommand{\getdec}[1]{\xintNum{\xintDecSplitR{0}{#1}}\relax}

\begin{document}
    The integer part: \xintNum{\x}\relax % Or just \getint{\x}
    
    The decimal part: \xintNum{\xintDecSplitR{0}{\x}}\relax % Or just \getdec{\x}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

From what I can tell from the [package documentation](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/generic/xint/xint.pdf):

`\xintNum{x}` truncates the fractional number `x` and returns an integer value.

`\xintDecSplit{n}{x}` cuts the number `x` into two pieces and returns two floats. If `n` is 0, then the split is performed at the decimal point. The corresponding command `\xintDecSplitR{n}{x}` returns the number on the right side after cutting, in this case, the decimal portion of `x`. I've had to wrap it in its own `\xintNum` to convert the float into an integer, so you don't get a spurious dot at the end.

Finally, it's possible to wrap the entire expression in your own custom commands, like I did with `\getint` and `\getdec` so it doesn't get messy in your main code.

Comment: The documentation is not clear enough that `\xintDecSplitR` is an *integer* only macro (in fact it is mainly used internally, but some forgotten reason I gave it a public interface). Thus the spurious dot is an after-effect from using the macro on unexpected input. It could have been spurious `!` or spurious `;` if I had coded it otherwise internally. By luck the dot indeed can be removed by `\xintNum`. Thanks for daring use of this macro, and next release 1.2o will improve the documentation.

Comment: I thus recommend rather egreg's approach, because this one works for accidental reasons. [xint](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) implemented decimal numbers at the same time as fractions and is lacking utilities which makes perfect sense for fixed point numbers only. Thus there is no high level one-shot interface to what is asked here.

Comment: @jfbu Ah no wonder the dot was appearing. Thanks a lot for the insightful explanation! I'll include a note in my answer for future visitors to refer to egreg's answer instead.

Comment: +1 for update, I have improved the docs for next release. I almost decided to add a macro for that task, but this will wait until `xint` is extended with a "Decimal" module.

Answer (score 3):

Just split the input at the period.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\intpart}[1]{\expandafter\int@part#1..\@nil}
\def\int@part#1.#2.#3\@nil{\if\relax#1\relax0\else#1\fi}

\newcommand{\fracpart}[1]{\expandafter\frac@part#1..\@nil}
\def\frac@part#1.#2.#3\@nil{\if\relax#2\relax0\else#2\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

59.3612: integral part \intpart{59.3612}, fractional part \fracpart{59.3612}

\def\x{59.3612}

\x: integral part \intpart\x, fractional part \fracpart\x

\def\x{42}

\x: integral part \intpart\x, fractional part \fracpart\x

\def\x{.3}

\x: integral part \intpart\x, fractional part \fracpart\x

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{fp}
\def\x{59.3612}
\begin{document}
\FPeval\front{round(\x:0)}
\FPeval\back{clip((\x-\front)*10000)}
\front\ and \back
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "*10000" - is it possible to automatically determine the size of the fractional part?

Comment: @user4035: I have no idea. Gave up!

Comment: I think it is easier and better to use strings. Easier code and more useful for big numbers or many digits because of the way latex sees float